# How to protect sensitive data in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, data-protection

This is for an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API project. We have purely on-premise implementation, so Azure Keyvault is not an option.

What is the other (except Azure Keyvault) best way to protect sensitive data like ApiKey, database connection string etc.?

How to handle that in different environments like in Development, Test, UAT, and Production environment?

Comment: Use app configuration Manager and reference the value from Keyvault.  This way you can protect the sensitive value.

Comment: @anirudha Gupta, I already mentioned that azure key vault cann't be implemented in the project. So, you need to suggest as per my requirement i..e without azure and it should be for on-premise implementation.

Comment: you can set up the environment variable in CI-CD. Same can be read in App.

Comment: couldn't understand what are all steps?

Comment: Till now I didn't get answer to my query. Please guide